# Append more validation functions with existing validations, ngrx-forms

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-forms

Is there any possibility to add new validation functions in form control state by keeping existing already attached validation functions intact?

I hade already added **required** function from my reducer function.

I have tried below code.

```
validate(myControl,[email])
```

But when I add above line, it removes all my previous validations.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a formcontrols with formBuilder like this:

```js
this.formBuilder.group({
      title: [this.title, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
```

or:

```js
new UntypedFormControl('', {validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]});
```

Comment: Question is about to add new add new validation with already existing validations by using ngrx-form.

Comment: sorry i missed the part of ngrx-form. next time write it in the question too, and not only in the title ;)

Comment: i never used ngrx but reading the doc, this should work: `validate(required, greaterThanOrEqualTo(2), lessThan(10)),``

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:

New validation functions can be added to the form control state while preserving existing validations. To achieve this, you need to use the `Validators.compose()` or `Validators.composeAsync()` functions provided by Angular.

Here is an example of how you can add a new validation function while still retaining existing functions.

```
 import { Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
        
        // Assume you already have a form control with some existing validators
        const myControl = new FormControl('', [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3)
        ]);
        
        // Define your new validation function
        const emailValidator = Validators.email;
        
        // Add the new validation function while keeping the existing validators intact
        myControl.setValidators(Validators.compose([myControl.validator, emailValidator]));
        myControl.updateValueAndValidity();
```